# How to put an image in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a `ListView` which displays list of images. When I click an image in that `ListView` I want to display the image in `AlertDialog`.

Using the following code I am able to get and display text form `TextView` in an `AletDialog`.
But I don't know how to display an image in an `AlertDialog`.

I referred many sources.But nothing helped.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
                    String value = c.getText().toString();

                    ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_temp);

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(uploadpage.this).
                            setTitle("title").
                            setMessage(value).
                            show();

                    dialog.show();
                }
            });

        }
```

**My question is how to display(inside `AlertDialog`) the particular Image of a  `ListVIew` when it is clicked ?**
I want to display the image or item which is clicked.

**EDIT**

```
01-24 14:31:26.504 17180-17180/com.example.prakash.pix91 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.prakash.pix91, PID: 17180
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:108)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:285)
                                                                               at com.example.prakash.pix91.uploadpage$6.onItemClick(uploadpage.java:507)
                                                                               at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3073)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3910)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: add custom view in dialog.

Comment: You can create a custom layout, take a reference from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Please try below answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Create one layout file for your image and this to your alert dialog

```
 AlertDialog.Builder   alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     LayoutInflater inflaterr = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View  viewtemplelayout= inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.imagefile, null);
      ImageView i = (ImageView) viewtemplelayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView_temp);//and set image to image view

         alertdialog.setView(viewtemplelayout);//add your view to alert dilaog
         alertdialog.show()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.I am getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: while clicking the item in listview

Comment: can you please post log

Comment: i think you are passing null context try to add getActivity()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133865/discussion-between-ganesh-patil-and-user7357013).

Answer (score 1):

Your AlertDialog's layout should include an ImageView to display the image. When you instantiate your dialog, you will pass it the image view from the ListView.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
// Set the resource for the image view
// image.setBitmap(someImageBitmapFromListView);
// You can also set a drawable using setImageResource(Drawable drawable) on the ImageView
AlertDialog aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(image)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null)
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
        .create();
aDialog.show();
```

Extracting the image from the ListView should be simple enough. If you only need to display the image, then the above code should get you started. If you want to display more then take a look at the official guide for creating custom dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should create your custom layout like this.

AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

ImageView imageview= (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
imageview.setImageResource(R.id.image1);
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

That's it.
```